# Generalization of topological functor which need not be fibre-complete

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

Is there a useful property for a concrete category $(\mathcal A, U : \mathcal A \to \mathcal X)$ such that in this case $U$ is fibre-complete iff $U$ is topological? (kind of like what "flat" is too "left exact).

The motivation is the following: given a finitely complete category $\mathcal X$ we can define the concrete category of $\mathcal X$-objects equipped with relations / reflexive relations / preorders / congruences / etc. . These seem to be topological iff the functor $U : (X,R) \mapsto X$ is fibre-complete (unless I'm mistaken).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean "topological" in [this sense](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category), probably with the strict condition that $U(T)=X$ and $g=id$.  In that case, an almost-answer is:

> $U$ is a bifibration in preorders.

A topological functor certainly has this property.  Conversely, if $U$ is a fibre-complete fibration in preorders, then given any $U$-structured source $(f_i : X \to U(S_i))$, we can form the family of reindexings $f_i^* S_i$ using the fibration structure and take their meet in the complete preorder $U^{-1}(X)$.  The initiality of this lift follows from the universal properties of cartesian arrows and meets, together with the fact that reindexing functors $g^*$ preserve meets, which follows from the fact that they have left adjoints because $U$ is also a bifibration.

Whether or not this is quite an answer depends on your definition of "fibre-complete" and size questions.  In order for the above argument to work, we need the fibers to have possibly *large* meets; a complete *small* preorder automatically has large meets, but in general the fibers of a topological functor may be large.  However if you define "fibre-complete" to mean the existence of *all* meets including large ones, then it works.

Comment: Excellent answer! The last paragraph is also very useful since this an issue I hadn't addressed yet. - Am I correct in thinking, that the above holds with "bifibration" replaced by "fibration and the reindexing functors preserve all infima"? Otherwise, I think, e.g. the example with the congruences wouldn't work (since there are not stable under images).

Comment: @StefanPerko Well, by the adjoint functor theorem, a functor between complete preorders that preserves all meets (including those of the size of the preorders themselves) automatically has a left adjoint; hence your condition is equivalent to being a bifibration.  Note that the left adjoints in a bifibration don't need to be given by set-theoretic images.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that I was thinking straight ;) thank you. - Yes, my point was: set-theoretic images of equivalence relations are not necessarily equivalence relations, instead on uses the adjoint functor theorem to get the left-adjoints; but that is not possible with the fibres being complete (as in the set-theoretic case); hence the need for this slight generalization of "bifribation".

Comment: @StefanPerko What I'm saying is that it's *not* actually a generalization, because the completeness condition you need to make the argument work is strong enough to ensure that it actually is a bifibration.

Answer (score 1):

If U is topological is equivalent to have:

- U is faithful
- U admits lifting of one source and one sink
- U is fibre complete

You can see this  in [1](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf), pp. 377, exercise 21C. also you can check  http://revistas.unal.edu.co/index.php/bolma/article/view/18271/19185

Comment: This is actually the same as my answer: initial liftings of unary sources and sinks is the same as being a bifibration, and in that case being faithful is the same as having preordered fibers.  (-: