# topological functor for n-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

There exist different notion of [topological functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category), for example as regards the lifting of sources (we can see different definitions [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272837/generalization-of-topological-functor-which-need-not-be-fibre-complete/272972#272972)).

I want to study this notion in n-categories; does there exist a definition of  topological 2-functor or n-topological category?

Note: I did some searching and found [this](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=G4krAAAAYAAJ&q=2-%20topological%20categories&dq=2-%20topological%20categories&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx8Oja0IPYAhUM7SYKHV2QDi0Q6AEILjAB), but I can't see the definition of topological 2-category in it.

Comment: I believe the link in your third paragraph is about topologically *enriched* categories, which as pointed out at your [other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288393/topological-categories-as-enriched-category) are totally unrelated.

Comment: As for your question, the notion of [n-fibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-fibration) is at least related.

Comment: Do you have any putative examples of such a notion? For example, a 2-category that you'd expect to be topological over $Cat$?

Comment: @MikeShulman I don't think the third link is about topically enriched categories but I can not be sure because I can't see the text(in the library where found the text don´t have a digital version).

Comment: The text I see on Google Books includes "there is a homomorphism $B E G \to G$, such that the continuous function between the morphism spaces has a homotopy inverse", which certainly sounds like it is talking about topologically enriched, or perhaps internal, categories.