# Topological categories as enriched category

Tags: ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory

Lurie define in [HTT](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HTT.pdf)(Def. 1.1.1.6) a topological category as a enriched category over compactly generated (and weakly Hausdorff) topological spaces, but usually we define a topological category as lifting of sources ([other definitions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category)).

My question: it's equivalent the definition of topological category of Lurie with the usually?

Note: Lurie mention: "I take that definition for convenience" (Pg. 7),  but he does not say anything about the connection with usual definition.

Comment: No, they are completely different concepts, as the second link you provide explains.

Comment: There are actually at least three things that "topological category" can mean. In order of prevalence, they are: 1. category enriched in $Top$, 2. category internal to $Top$, 3. the notion defined in terms of sinks. (1) can be regarded as a special case of (2), but as Marc says, they are completely unrelated to (3). I think it's fair to say that most mathematicians outside of pure category theory are completely unaware of usage (3), whereas usage (1) and maybe (2) are well-known to many mathematicians in other areas (especially those in Lurie's audience who might use higher category theory.)